# Есть ли разница указывать header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); или <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">?

Tags: php, html, header, charset

Еще я указывал "AddDefaultCharset utf-8", но разницу не понял

Comment: Никакой разницы, это одно и то же.

Comment: Я думаю, что пихать http-заголовки в html-код — это костыль, применять который в 2022 году не надо

Answer (score 0):

В спецификации [HTML 4.01 в разделе 5.2.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#h-5.2.2) «Указание кодировки символов» четко указано, что информация в заголовке HTTP имеет приоритет над meta-тегом. [HTML 5 не меняет этого поведения](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#determining-the-character-encoding), а лишь дополняет относительно метки порядка байтов (BOM). Meta-тег, определяющий кодировку символов, вступает в силу, если информация о кодировке отсутствует в заголовке HTTP, или при наличии метки порядка байтов (BOM). Вообще,  клиент по некоторым причинам может не принять информацию о кодировке в заголовке Content-Type, также HTML-документ может быть открыт локально, так что HTTP-заголовки вообще могут отсутствовать. Когда пользователь сохраняет HTML-документ на своем устройстве, заголовки HTTP не сохраняются. Это основная причина использования Meta-тега для указания кодировки символов. И в этом случае он конечно должен указывать правильную кодировку.

Answer (score -1):

конечно есть.

такой header насколько помню равносилен указанию myme-type в htaccess, а он насильно заставит браузер открывать любой output как html страницу, бинарник? парсим как html. mp3? тоже парсим как html. прям как css !important =)

а тег  только кодировку задает - он срабатывает уже после того как браузер решил именно парсить контент как html\xhtml, а если парсинг не начнется, этот тег и не сработает.